# CNN good results on train and test, bad results on real world data

Tags: neural-network, cnn, image-classification, transfer-learning, data-augmentation

I'm trying to build a neural network for an age detection task.
Here some details :

1. Dataset: I am using the "facial age" Kaggle dataset and the "UTKFace" dataset for a total of about 35k images
   I've divided the total dataset in train, dev and test set (70%-15%-15%) and I've applied data augmentation on the train set
2. Task: Age detection, 8 class classification problem
3. Model: I've applied transfer learning on ResNet-50, keras implementation

Model:

[image]

Results:

[image]

[image]

On the test set the model return an accuracy of 85.5% but on real world images (google images or personal photos) the model perform a lot worse (about 45%). The images of the real world I've choosen are quite similar to those of the datasets, it's not possible for an human eye to distinguish them.

Where is the problem ? What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: To me it's suspicious that the validation accuracy is significantly higher than the training one. I would suspect something messed up in the data.

Comment: Agree with @Erwan. BTW I'd suggest manually running some test images through the model and inspect the results manually for any weird thing.

Comment: @Erwan From what I know about this situation, it is because of the use of many Dropout layers. In the training phase a certain percentage of features are not considered, depending on the Dropout layer, instead in the testing phase all features are always used so the model is more robust and can lead to higher accuracy. I don't think it's a completely weird situation and I'm not sure this is the problem. 
[discussion on val acc > train acc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979449/higher-validation-accuracy-than-training-accurracy-using-tensorflow-and-keras).

Comment: @Erwan  I've checked the data many times but I can't find any strange thing. 
Is it possible that the problem is only the difference between the datasets I used and the real data ?

Comment: @lpounng What do you mean specifically? I've visualized some test and real images and they seems very similar. I've also runned some test images one at a time through the model and the results are consistent.

Comment: @Daniel_Fortesque ok thanks, I didn't know. It makes sense, but then I think it could be interesting to apply the model normally (with all features) on the training set, this could tell you whether you have overfitting. Otherwise it could be because the test set is not representative enough of the target data, indeed.

Comment: @Erwan I've applied the model without Dropout layers and I get 99% accuracy on train set and 85.5% on the test set (as before). So what can we say about that, aside from that the Dropout layers worked well to avoid overfitting ?

Answer (score 0):

1. As per @Erwan, it is suspicious that the validation accuracy is significantly higher than the training one. Try K-fold validation and see if this is true for all folds; if they all show this kind of behavior, there is  something seriously wrong with your data/code.
2. Double-check if you have shuffle dataset before/while splitting into train/val/test. Chance is a lot of 'easy' images have fallen into validation/test set.
3. The 'real world' images may have some properties/distributions which are different from training data, yet undetected by naked eyes. If you have the resources, try labeling a few batches of real world images, append to the training set, and see if it impacts (lowers) the accuracy during training.

P.S.: please, [do not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: 1. As I mentioned in the comments it's because of the Dropout layers, it's not a weird situation. [discussion on val acc > train acc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979449/higher-validation-accuracy-than-training-accurracy-using-tensorflow-and-keras)   


2. I've shuffled the dataset before splitting it into train/val/test
3. I'll try your suggestion, but it's not easy to get a high number of face images from web. I have collected 300 images manually from web but I don't know if they can have an impact on a training set of ~25k images

Comment: Forgive me, but if you keep insisting 'nothing's wrong', 'cannot do', there is no way we can help nor explain why your test accuracy is low. Be skeptical and assume we are wrong to start with - this is the heart of science.

Comment: If the set of real-world data is too small, you may try oversampling or assigning a heavier weight to them.